# Removing a tire

Tags: tire, replacement, restoration

I have an older bike with a blown tube. I don't have the money to replace the tire but I have the tube. The tire is quite old probably at least ten years old since that is when the last owner bought the bike. Is there a way to remove the tire without wrecking it or am I going to have to wait till I can afforded a new tire.

Comment: Rule #1:  DON'T USE A SCREWDRIVER!!  Invest a buck or two in some plastic "tire levers".

Comment: I do have those so it is possible to to remove without ruining?

Comment: Someone who knows what they're doing has about a 99% chance of removing a standard tire from a standard rim without causing damage.  https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/tire-and-tube-removal-and-installation

Comment: Please answer in answers, not comments.

Comment: OK then I should be fine. This is IMO the most basic repair on a bike thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the tyre's safe to ride on, removing and replacing it shouldn't damage it, as long as you use the correct tools. These are tyre levers, which can be bought for literally a couple of dollars/euros/pounds. The internet will tell you how to do this; it's not difficult.

If the tyre can't be removed without damaging it, then it's not safe to ride.

Comment: Tire seems safe very little dry rot from sitting for sitting in a barn my main problem with this restore is rust and seized parts

Comment: **NO!!!!** "Very little dry rot" is too much. You need none. A rotten tyre is not safe to ride. It could kill you.

Comment: Valid point. Guess I'm going to have to order new ones. Its just a pain to find good 26" 1-3/8 tires where im at in canada

Answer (score 3):

Tires are designed to be removable from rims and re-installed. For instance, to replace or repair a blown inner tube.

If the tire is a little old, you may have to exercise a little more caution. There are many video tutorials available to show you what the proper tools are, and how to remove the tire, remove and replace the tube and replace the tire properly.

Here's a good one: https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/tire-and-tube-removal-and-installation.